# Error while training rasa core

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I am using `rasa nlu` and `rasa core`.

I am trying out a restaurant example from [this `github` link](https://github.com/RasaHQ/). I got stuck at the below step. The error log is not brief or I am not able to get any clue:

The command that I am using is:

```
python -m rasa_core.train -s examples/restaurantbot/data/babi_stories.md 
  -d examples/restaurantbot/restaurant_domain.yml -o models/dialogue 
  --epochs 300**
```

What do you think is going wrong here?

---

Command `pip show rasa_core`

```
Name: rasa-core
Version: 0.10.4
Summary: Machine learning based dialogue engine for conversational software.
Home-page: https://rasa.com
Author: Rasa Technologies GmbH
Author-email: hi@rasa.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\users\bcn\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages
Requires: h5py, ruamel.yaml, networkx, tqdm, tensorflow, typing, requests, graphviz, jsonpickle, colorhash, numpy, fakeredis, python-telegram-bot, coloredlogs, six, twilio, pykwalify, scikit-learn, fbmessenger, redis, flask-cors, ConfigArgParse, flask, slackclient, matte
rmostwrapper, future, rasa-nlu, keras, apscheduler
Required-by:
```

Full error trace:

```
PS C:\System\MY FOLDER\test\Python\Restaurant\rasa_core-master> python -m rasa_core.train -s examples/restaurantbot/data/babi_stories.md -d examples/restaurantbot/restaurant_domain.yml -o models/dialogue --epochs 300

C:\Users\bcn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py:34: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type

  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bcn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\bcn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\System\MY FOLDER\test\Python\Restaurant\rasa_core-master\rasa_core\train.py", line 155, in <module>
    additional_arguments)
  File "C:\System\MY FOLDER\test\Python\Restaurant\rasa_core-master\rasa_core\train.py", line 106, in train_dialogue_model
    max_history=max_history))])
  File "C:\System\MY FOLDER\test\Python\Restaurant\rasa_core-master\rasa_core\policies\keras_policy.py", line 47, in __init__
    if KerasPolicy.is_using_tensorflow() and not graph:
  File "C:\System\MY FOLDER\test\Python\Restaurant\rasa_core-master\rasa_core\policies\keras_policy.py", line 64, in is_using_tensorflow
    from keras.backend import _BACKEND
  File "C:\Users\bcn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\bcn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "C:\Users\bcn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "C:\Users\bcn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "C:\Users\bcn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\bcn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\bcn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "C:\Users\bcn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "C:\Users\bcn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Answer (score 1):

After [looking up some other posts online](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/5046), this seems to be an issue with Python versions below 3.6.1.

Other than that, you can try reverting to `protobuf 3.6.0`

Lemme know if this solves your problem